# infinite "node restart" when using roslaunch

Tags: roslaunch, rosnode

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Using rosrun my node ends normally, but roslaunching it I get an infinite auto-restart; after the return 0 on "int main" the node gets called forever. I tried to comment out the spinOnce call without success. Diamondback on ubuntu 10.10

Thank you!!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11814/infinite-%22node-restart%22-when-using-roslaunch/) by [Bemfica](https://answers.ros.org/users/540/bemfica/) on ROS Answers with karma: 482 on 2011-11-05

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Sounds like you are setting the `respawn=true` attribute in the launch file for that node.

---

Originally posted by [joq](https://answers.ros.org/users/25/joq/) with karma: 25443 on 2011-11-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4